# Why input string may be non-zero terminated, when loaded into heap in risc-v?

Tags: assembly, user-input, heap-memory, riscv

I have stumbled upon a quite strange issue, when dealing with risc-v assembly (I use RARS 1.5 environment).

My goal is to write a program, which would create a copy of some file, if provided with the path to the source file (copied one) and target file (which is to store the copy) + size of the buffering window.

I use `sbrk` syscall in order to allocate space in heap memory, when saving strings, which I input.
The code, I have written for inputting paths (providing the macros I use as well):

```s
    .text

    .eqv src          s0
    .eqv trg          s1
    .eqv buffer       s2
    .eqv src.d        s3
    .eqv trg.d        s4


    .macro ssbrk(%immed)
    li a0, %immed
    li a7, 9
    ecall
    .end_macro

    .macro read_dir(%var)
    mv a0, %var
    li a1, 256       # the path length is supposed to be 256-bytes-long by given
    li a7, 8
    ecall
    newline
    .end_macro

    .macro open_file.read(%name)
    li a7, 1024
    mv a0, %name
    li a1, 0
    ecall
    .end_macro

    .macro null.exit()
    li a7, 10
    ecall
    .end_macro

    j main
UNABLE_TO_OPEN_FILE:
    print_str("An error has occured: Failed to open file.\n Program will be terminated.")
    null.exit()
main:
    print_str("Please, input the path to the source file to be copied:\n")
    ssbrk(256)
    mv src, a0
    read_dir(src)

    print_str("Please, input the path to the target file, to copy source to:\n")
    ssbrk(256)
    mv trg, a0
    read_dir(trg)

    print_str("Please, specify the size of buffer for storing data from source file:\n")
    int_input(buffer)

    open_file.read(src)
    bltz  a0, UNABLE_TO_OPEN_FILE
    mv    src.d, a0 # source file descriptor
    ...
    ## the latter part of my program is ommited, as there is no issue, regarding further operations ##
```

When my console-input sequence is:

```
Console: Please, input the path to the source file to be copied:
User0: /home/acos/Desktop/text_dir.txt
Console: Please, input the path to the target file, to copy source to:
User0: /home/acos/Desktop/text_dir(1).txt
Console: ...
...
```

The first "address" string with source file, for some reason is saved to heap without "\0", whilst the second sttring is saved, being zero-terminated.

Hence, when I try to pass this very source address from heap to file opener, it throws an exception, since string is non-zero-terminated.

I am sure, that apart from inputting strings my program works correctly, since I have tested it by creating two data segments with `.asciz "\path\"`to src and trg, and everything worked nicely.

I have absolutely no idea about what may be wrong, so I would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with system calls on riscv, but `read` system calls do not null-terminate the data they read.  You have to do it yourself.  Nor is `sbrk` memory guaranteed to be filled with zeros (it could be part of a page that already belonged to your process).

Comment: I expected that `read` call won't null-terminate the string, but i don't understand why it does null-terminate target string, while not null-terminates the source string...
Another issue, is that when I try to input: "/home/.../source.txt\0", it doesn't read \0 for some reason, and still writes to the heap, as if the string wasn't zero-terminated, in heap it occurs as: "/home/.../source.txt\", and I don't get why it may happen.
Anyways, thank you for contribution!

Comment: It probably doesn't; I suspect that the next byte in memory after the target string just coincidentally happens to be a zero.  You're depending on the contents of uninitialized memory so you shouldn't expect reliable behavior.  Just do the null termination, since you know it's needed; there's not much point in trying to understand the precise way in which known buggy code misbehaves.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by try to input "/home/.../source.txt\0".  Where is this input coming from?  If you're typing it on the terminal, typing `\0` won't read a null byte; it will read a backslash followed by the numeral 0.  For testing, you might be able to type an actual null character with `Ctrl-@`, if that's something your system supports.

Comment: I got your point about adding null-termination artificially, but the problem is that i do not really understand how can I append '\0' to my string, I have tried to google how to append a character to a string in assembly, but have found nothing really useful.

Then I tried to use riscv-toolchain to translate a simple c++ code, which appends a character to a string, but it seems to be to complicated, since in c++ string objects use their own constructor, which makes it quite hard to understand, when translated to assembly.

Comment: I don't know riscv assembly well, but the idea would be to compute the address where the null byte should go, by taking the starting address `src` and adding the number of bytes read (which the `read` system call should have returned).  Then store a zero byte at that address.  To ensure this doesn't overrun the allocated space, you should probably read one byte less than the space you have allocated (e.g. allocate 256 bytes and read 255).  Also watch out for the case when the `read()` fails, typically returning a negative number.

Comment: The C equivalent would be something like `r = read(fd, buf, 255); if (r >= 0) buf[r] = 0; else die();`  Generally, when trying to learn assembly through compiler output, C is likely to be more useful than C++, since it does a lot less behind-the-scenes magic.

Comment: That's not how `ecall` `#8` works on RARS.  (It works like MARS `syscall` `#8`).  It only reads from the console so doesn't take a file descriptor; it terminates the string with a newline and a nul character terminator (unless the buffer is filled full by the user input).  Maybe the newline that it appends is throwing you?  Have you looked at  the data after the ecall?  We don't have to guess -- we can run the debugger!

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I have run the debugger, and it appears that newline is not saved at all in heap, if it appears at the end of console input. Rather, when i input a string, it seems, like (somehow), when read by opener from heap, \0 is added to the end of any string, if the path is short enough and some bytes in allocated memory are left untouched, what seems quite strange. Anyways, i think i'll take a closer look tomorrow, since it's nearly 3 a.m. in my country, so brain refuses to think :)